# Change php header using switch case

Tags: php

I want to redirect to other page based on the selected string in combo box.

I have added following code:

```
switch ($downloadType){
    case "text1":
        header("Location:pdf/text1.pdf");
        break;
    case "text2":
        header("Location:pdf/text2.pdf");
    case "text3":
        header("Location:pdf/text3.pdf");
    default:
        header("Location:index.html");
}
```

But this simple script is not working. I am new to php. Do you have any idea why I am not able to change header. Is it like we cannot change header using switch-case statements.

If this is not the way then what could be the possible way to redirect to another page on form submission.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a break; to the end of each case.

```
case "text3": 
    header("Location:pdf/text3.pdf"); 
    break;
```

Comment: @Shruti: Jon is correct.  Also don't forget the `exit()` after your desired header(s) are sent.

Comment: Thanks alot! another query I have is.. I want to open pdf in new window instead of same window...  how to open new window on form submit in php.. I cannot use action here correct?

Comment: PHP is server side so cannot open a new window. You can do this is JavaScript or I think just using a target in an anchor. Either way, probably best to open a separate question for it if you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add break:

```
switch ($downloadType){
case "text1":
    header("Location:pdf/text1.pdf");
    break;
case "text2":
    header("Location:pdf/text2.pdf");
    break;
case "text3":
    header("Location:pdf/text3.pdf");
    break;
default:
    header("Location:index.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must see [switch](http://es.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statements as a sort of *jump to* construct. Depending on the value of the evaluated expression, code execution jumps to the first appropriate `case` or `default` statement and continues from there. That's why you'll want to insert a `break` statement most of the times. Currently, you only do it for the `"text1"` case.

Apart from that, I suggest you use full URLs when composing `Location` HTTP headers, even though relative URLs normally work as expected. The HTTP specification doesn't really allow relative URLs.

```
header('Location: http://example.com/foo/pdf/text2.pdf');
```

And don't forget that sending an HTTP header does not stop the script execution. Add an `exit;` statement when you're done.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from completing your case statements with break, also remember that you must call header() before any actual output is sent.

E.g:

```
<html>
<?php
header("Location:pdf/text2.pdf");?>
</html>
```

Will not work, since the "`<html>`" line will already have been sent to the client, precluding the use of header(). Basically, make sure no output is going on in the file before you try to call header().

Edit:
Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php